# Get the user's name out of a full string of text

Tags: c#, chatbot

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.WriteLine("BubbleBot: Hello! What's your name?");
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.ResetColor();

while (!shutdown)
{
    foundResponse = false;

    Console.Write("You: ");
    inputValue = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    Console.WriteLine("");

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    Console.Write("BubbleBot: ");
    switch(inputValue)
    {
        case "My name is ":
            foundResponse = true;
            outputValue = "Hello,";
            break;
```

I'm trying to make a chat bot and I want to make sure that the chat bot only sees text as the user's name if the words "my name is" come before it. I'm not sure if this is possible, and if so, how can i accomplish it?
(basically i'm trying to state that any word(s) that come after "My name is" should be set as the string, "userName")

Comment: `int index = inputValue.IndexOf("My name is "); if (index != -1) { /* Found it */ }`

Comment: Look into `string.StartsWith` (and likely `string.ToLower()`).

Comment: Keep in mind your "My name is " case won't ever be hit due to .ToLower() on the input.

Answer (score 1):

In short, use a `Name Finder` tool.

If your serious about developing a chatbot scrubbing user text responses is going to make you hate this project in no time.  I would recommend using `Natural Language Processing (NLP)` and use a `Parts of Speech (POS)` tagging library like SharpNLP.

> My name is John Doe

The will be broken up into parts of speech.  Subject and predicate.  It will be further divided into subject nouns, verbs, adjectives, and predicate nouns, and even Proper Nouns which is what you want.  Here is a list of the tools within SharpNLP.

- a sentence splitter
- a tokenizer
- a part-of-speech tagger
- a chunker (used to "find non-recursive syntactic annotations such as noun phrase chunks")
- a parser
- **a name finder**
- a coreference tool
- an interface to the WordNet lexical database

*A rare black squirrel has become a regular visitor to a suburban garden*
[image: A rare black squirrel has become a regular visitor to a suburban garden]

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sharpnlp

Better yet, if this was a learning exercise, I would look into what Microsoft, Google and Amazon AI have already done and learn to use their APIs.

Answer (score 0):

This would help you solve your immediate problem.

```
var nameIndicator = "my name is ";
var index = inputValue.ToLower().IndexOf(nameIndicator);

if (index == -1)
{
    // Not found
}
else
{
    var name = inputValue.Substring(index + nameIndicator.Length);
}
```

The variable `name` will extract whatever comes after "My name is " as the name.

However I strongly encourage you to rethink your approach here as this is *very* error prone. What if the user made a typo? Also, from a UX point of view, a nobody ever wants to type "My name is XYZ" when asked for name, you just type your name.

What you can do is simply ask for the name and get user input as the name.

### NOTE

When you post code samples please post complete samples where they can be run without edits.
If it's too long, see here how you can post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).